# Export Excel File not open into excel in window 7

Tags: excel, grails, ubuntu, window, export

I'm using  Ubuntu and  facing problem.In my application using export plug-in in grails when I'm uploading file into local server so that getting the export file  but this file not open into ms-office excel in window 7 but proper work in Ubuntu Lib re Office Cal how to fix it this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension of the file If Used the extension of Excel file XLSX instead of use XLS This ll work properly